# show that $ \ 0 \leq aa_1-b<a $.

Tags: real-analysis

If $ \ r=\frac{a}{b}<1 \ $ and $ \ a_1=\min \{q \in \mathbb{N}: \frac{1}{q} \leq \frac{a}{b} \} $ , then show that $ \ 0 \leq aa_1-b<a $.

**Answer:**

Since $ \ a_1=\min \{q \in \mathbb{N}: \frac{1}{q} \leq \frac{a}{b} \} $ , we have $a_1=\min \{ q \in \mathbb{N}: q \geq \frac{b}{a} \} \Rightarrow a _1 \geq \frac{b}{a} \Rightarrow aa_1-b \geq 0 , ...............(1)$

Next we have to show that, $ \ aa_1-b<a $

Since $ r=\frac{a}{b}<1 , \Rightarrow a <b $.

Also by  definition of $ a_1$ , we have

$a_1 \geq 2$ . Thus $ \ a_1-1 \geq 1$.

Now, $ 
\ aa_1-b<aa_1-a=a(a_1-1) \leq a,..............(2) $

$(\because a<b \ \ and \ \ a_1-1 \geq 1)$

Thus from (1) and (2)

$ 0 \leq aa_1-b \leq a $

But we have to show $ 0 \leq aa_1-b <a $.

Help me

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

In the last step, you actually HAVE proven that $aa_1-b < a$.

See, $a < b \leq c$ means $a < c$, not $a \leq c$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $aa_1-b=a$. Then $a_1=1+\frac{b}{a}$.

This implies that $a_1-1=\frac{b}{a}$, so $a_1-1$ would be a natural number $\ge \frac{b}{a}$. But by assumption $a_1$ is the minimal natural number $\ge \frac{b}{a}$.

Thus, $aa_1-b\ne a$.